# Describe a non-deterministic 2-tape Turing machine

Tags: computability, turing-machines

I want to find a non-deterministic 2-tape Turing machine, that accepts the language L over $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ in $n$ steps, with input of length $n$, $L=\{x1y \mid |y|=2|x|>0\}$.

Should the Turing machine do the following?

Each time that the machine reads 1 it should check if the length of the subword before 1 is equal to the half of the length of the subword after 1.

How can this be done by a non-deterministic 2-tape Turing machine? Could you give me a hint?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

The idea is the following:

We have to guess the position of $1$. In the state $z_1$ we copy the input of the first tape, till this $1$, to the second one. Then after having reached $1$, the head of the first tape will make $|x|$ to the right. If the input ends there, the input is accepted. If not, the input is rejected.

Is this correct?

Is the transition function then the following?

$(z_0, 1, \square)\mapsto (z_0,1,1,R,R) \mid (z_1, X,X,N,N)$

$(z_0, 0, \square)\mapsto (z_0,0,0,R,R)$

$(z_1, a, \square)\mapsto (z_1, a,a,R,R)$

$(z_1, X,X)\mapsto (z_2, a, \square, R, N)$

$(z_2, a, \square)\mapsto (z_2, a, \square, R, N)$

$(z_2,\square, \square )\mapsto (z_3, \square, \square, N, N)$

Comment: Please, explain what you mean by "accept the language" as it could mean several thing for a turing machine : reach a particular state, write a particular output on a specific tape, or just halt.

Comment: A language $L$ is acceptable, if there is a Turing machine $M$, with $L(M)=L$. @Xoff

Comment: What does it mean $L(M)$ ?

Comment: The Turing machine reaches an accepting state for any input from the language. @Xoff

Comment: So, this question is weird, because there is no need in a second tape, as being non deterministic, the machine doesn't need to write anything to reach an accepting state on $L$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the machine doesn't need to write anything to reach an accepting state on $L$" ? @Xoff

Comment: Oops sorry, I read that $|y|=2$ and not $|y|=2|x|$, ok, you may need (but it's a convenience only) the second tape to verify that length of $y$ is twice the length of $x$.

Comment: I suppose $N$ is no move in your solution ? So you never goes left ??

Comment: Yes, $N$ means no move. I thought the following: At $z_0$ we copy the inout of the tape 1 to tape 2 and if we reach the guessed position of 1, we stop. In $z_1$ we count the number of symbols in the tape 1, after the guessed position. So, the transition function is not correct, is it? @Xoff

Comment: When you copy on tape 2, you go right on each tape. When you reach the guessed position, $y$ is on your right on tape 1, but the copy of $x$ is on your left on tape 2. To compare them, you need to go left on the tape 2 at some step, or you could never retrieve the copied information.

Comment: Should it be as follows? $$(z_0, 1, \square)\mapsto (z_0,1,1,R,R) \mid (z_1, X,X,N,N) \\ 
(z_0, 0, \square)\mapsto (z_0,0,0,R,R) \\ 
(z_1, a, \square)\mapsto (z_1, a,a,R,R) \\ 
(z_1, X,X)\mapsto (z_2, a, a, R, L) \\ 
(z_2, a, a)\mapsto (z_2, a, a, R, L) \\ 
(z_2, a, \square)\mapsto (z_2, a, a, R, R) \\ 
(z_2,\square, \square )\mapsto (z_3, \square, \square, N, N)$ @Xoff

Comment: You will need two states to verify that $|y|=2|x|$ (because each time you read one letter of $y$ you need to read two letters of $x$), your 3rd transition is useless (unreachable).

Comment: Should it be: $$(z_0, 1, \square)\mapsto (z_0,1,1,R,R) \mid (z_1, X,X,N,N) \\ (z_0, 0, \square)\mapsto (z_0,0,0,R,R)\\ (z_1, X,X)\mapsto (z_2, a, a, R, L) \\ (z_2, a, a)\mapsto (z_2, a, a, R, L) \\ (z_2, a, \square)\mapsto (z_3, a, a, R, R) \\ (z_3, a, a)\mapsto (z_3, a, a, R,R) $$ ? Then when we get $(z_3, a, \square)$ or $(z_3, \square, a)$ the input is not accepted, but when we get $(z_3,\square, \square )$ the input is accepted, sp $(z_3,\square, \square )\mapsto (z_4, \square, \square, N, N)$. Is this correct? @Xoff

Comment: Try it on 0100 or 0010000 and fix the problem.

Comment: For $0100$ we have the following: 
$$$$ 
In the state $z_0$ we copy the first symbol, $0$ to the second tape. Then we reach the guessed position $1$. 
Then we have to move the head of the first head at the symbol after $1$, and the head of the second tape at the symbol before $1$. 
Then the head of the first tape has to move once to the right, and the head of the seond tape should not move. Then we see that the property holds. @Xoff

Comment: For $0010000$ we have the following: 
In the state $z_0$ we copy the first two symbols, to the second tape. Then we reach the guessed position $1$. 
Then we have to move the head of the first head at the symbol after $1$, and the head of the second tape at the symbol before $1$. 
Then the head of the first tape has to move once to the right, and the head of the second tape should not move.

Comment: Then the head of the first tape has to move once to the right, and the head of the second tape once to the left. Then the head of the first tape has to move once to the right, and the head of the second tape should not move. Then we see that the property holds.

Comment: As @Xoff already said, your TM does not retrieve the information you have stored on your second tape. You would know that if you actually followed the machine. You're not allowed to "see by human ingenuity that the property holds". The TM must mechanically determine the answer, by reaching an accepting or rejecting state. And TMs cannot count; they just write, move and change state.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you have non-determinism, just copy the input to the second tape up to some guessed position (intended to be just before the "1"), and then check that the next symbol on the input tape is "1" and that the rest of the input is twice as long as what is on the second tape. Clearly any string in $L$ will be accepted for some sequence of guesses, and also any accepted string is in $L$. Just ensure that you handle the small cases correctly and don't accept "1".

It is (of course) also possible with a deterministic TM, but it uses $2n$ steps and is more troublesome. The easiest way is to read the first symbol of the input, and then read the rest in threes, each time appending one symbol to the second tape. After that, you know exactly where the "1" in the middle is supposed to be, and you can just read the input backwards from the end (where you last stopped) and check that the symbol at that location is really a "1".

Comment: How does then the transition function look like? How do we describe the guessed position?

Comment: @MaryStar: That's for you to figure out. To guess the position just means that at each step of my first sentence you non-deterministically either stop (guess it is there) or carry on.

Comment: But how can we formally define the guessed position? I got stuck right now... How can we know where we have to stop?

Comment: @MaryStar: I think you need to revise the definition of a non-deterministic TM. It is trivial to make it do what I've explained in my previous comment.

Comment: Could you take a look at the edit part of my question? Is the transition function correct?

Comment: @MaryStar: Note that everybody's definition of TMs is different so you should always define what a transition function is. What is "N"? If it means "don't move", then your TM cannot be correct because you're not using what you wrote on the second tape at all. And you mean "in state $z_0$ we copy ...". Try your own TM on an actual input. Think how you would get it to count off twice as many symbols after the '1' as before it.

Answer (score 0):

Transitions are described with (Initial state, read (tape1), read (tape2)) -> (newState, write(tape1), write(tape2), move(tape1), move(tape2)).

I also suppose that the head is initially placed on the first (leftmost) letter of the input word (or blank if empty). Letters are 0,1 or B (blank).

The initial state is $I$, the acceptance state is $A$, the rejected state is $R$. The non deterministic machine accepts a word if it has at least one computation path that reach $A$.

- $(I,0,B) \rightarrow (J,0,0,N,R)$
- $(J,0,B) \rightarrow (I,0,0,R,R)$
- $(I,1,B) \rightarrow (J,0,0,N,R) | (K,B,B,R,L)$
- $(K,0|1,0) \rightarrow (K,0,0,R,L)$
- $(K,B,B) \rightarrow (A,B,B,N,N)$

Any non defined transition goes to state $R$ (rejection).

The idea : First we use states $I$ and $J$ to write twice many 0 as we read 0 or 1 on tape 1. Then we compare the number of written 0 on tapes 2 with the number of 0 or 1 of the guessed $y$ with state $K$

Comment: And why does any defined transition go to state $R$ ?

Comment: "non defined" or should I wrote undefined ? @MaryStar