# Travelling Salesman Problem - Find the tour

Tags: computational-complexity, computability

We are given the input for TSP with $6$ points with the following distances: 
 [image]

I want to find the approximation for a TSP-Tour using the NEAREST NEIGHBOR and the NEAREST INSERTION by starting by the vertex $1$.

Do we have the following graph from the above table?

[image]

Using the NEAREST NEIGHBOR we start by the vertex $1$ and then we visit at each step a non-visited vertex with the minimum distance, right?
So using this algorithm we get the following Tour: 
$$1\rightarrow 6\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 1$$ with total distance $48$

or

$$1\rightarrow 6\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 1$$ with total distance $49$

right?

The NEAREST INSERTION is the following:

```
T <- {1} 
while |T|<n do 
   j <- vertex with minimal d(T,j), j notin T 
   insert j with minimal cost into T 
return T
```

where $d(T,j)=\min_{i\in T}d(i,j)$ and the costs, to add $j$ between $i$ and $k$ are $\text{cost}(j)=\min_{(i,k)\in T} d(i,j)+d(j,k)-d(i,k)$

So using this algorithm we get the following:

```
T = {1} 
j = 6 , d(1,6)=2 
T = {1,6} 
j = 2 , d(1,2)=3 
T = {1,6,2} 
j = 4 , d(1,4)=d(6,4)=4 
T={1,6,2,4} 
j = 3 , d(2,3)=d(4,3)=10  or   j = 5 , d(4,5)=d(6,5)=10 
T = {1,6,2,4,3}                T = {1,6,2,4,5}
j = 5 , d(4,5)=d(6,5)=10       j = 3 , d(4,3)=d(2,3)=10
T = {1,6,2,4,3,5}              T = {1,6,2,4,5,3}
```

So, with this algorithm we get following tours: 
$$1\rightarrow 6\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 1$$ with total distance $53$

or

$$1\rightarrow 6\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 1$$ with total distance $54$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nearest neighbour, I found 1,6,4,2,3,5 for 2+4+5+10+20+11=52. I put 2 after 4 because it's only distance 5.

For nearest insertion :

1. 1
2. 6 : [1,6] T=6
3. 2 : [1,6,2] T=10
4. 4 : [1,6,4,2] T=14 (and not 16 with [1,6,2,4])
5. 3 then 5 : [1,6,4,3,2] T=29, [1,6,5,4,3,2] T=45

Comment: Could you maybe take a look also at my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890594/describe-a-non-deterministic-2-tape-turing-machine ?